# How to retain only current month's data using Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe which has some dates of the current month (i.e. March) although my requirement is only to have past 1 month's data (i.e. for now - February). Since this file will be available for each month, I want to kind of automate it. Which function to use? Date is in dd-mm-yyyy format

Sample Input

```
Date | Value
02-02-2021 | 15
03-02-2021 | 12
1-03-2021  | 20
```

Sample Output

```
Date | Value
02-02-2021 | 15
03-02-2021 | 12
```

How to achieve this? Dataframe has 30K rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve just by:-

Firstly convert your **Date** column in `datetime` dtype by(If its already in datetime dtype then ignore this step):-

```
df['Date']=pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
```

Finally:-

```
df['Month']=df['Date'].dt.month
```

Comment: Thank you! This helped me to filter my data.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']) # if the column is not in datetime format
date = datetime.now().date - timedelta(days=30)
df = df[df['Date'] >= date]
```

Answer (score 0):

I was not sure if you need the actual month plus the previose or not. So i did both. I always start at the first of the month. So it does not always have 30/31 entries. If your column is already in a date format you can skip `to_datetime(df['Date'])` but you need the `.dt.date` for comparison reason.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['05/03/2021', '02/03/2021', '01/01/2021'],
                   'Value': [2, 3, 5]})
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.date
startDate = date.today()
startDate = startDate.replace(day=1)
filtered_df = df[df['Date'] >= startDate]
print(filtered_df)

# If you also want to have the previose month as well
lastMonth = (startDate.month + 11) % 12
startDate = startDate.replace(month=lastMonth)
filtered_df = df[df['Date'] >= startDate]
print(filtered_df)
```

Comment: NameError: name 'date' is not defined --> error, when I am executing your exact code.

Comment: you need to add ```from datetime import date```